# How to code a simple stepped counter based on a select sentence

Tags: mysql, select, counter

I am trying to create a store procedure that returns as many rows as numbers in a sequence [0..max], incrementing values with a given step. The same result we would expect from a for-loop with step.
I am having a hard time trying to replicate this behaviour on a SQL select basis.

This is my first MySQL approach, returning no rows.
The expected output should be

```
10
20
30
...
1000
```

Any idea of what's going wrong here?

```
delimiter $$

create procedure counter (
  _step int,
  _max int
)
begin
  select 
    @x := @x + _step as xcount
  from 
    (select @x := 0) ts
  where
    @x <= _max;
end;
$$

call counter(10, 1000);
```

A DBFiddle also here 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wtwhT7U4Edu6d3t6gwqAJ5/1

### Solution

@Straberry suggestion leads to the following simpler solution, available in MySQL v8. Unfortunately, DBFiddle fails to reproduce the result. You have to try in a local MySQL v8 server.

```
with recursive cte (n) as (
  select 10
  union all
  select n + 10 from cte where n < 500
) select * from cte;
```

More examples and counters in
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples

Comment: You appear to be using MySQL 5.7. Interested in upgrading?

Comment: Just upgraded to 8 in DBFiddle. No difference.

Comment: But 8 offers a whole new spectrum of possibilities for this kind of problem; that's the point.

Comment: All of that said, keep in mind that sql is for the storage and retrieval of relational data; and not much else.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry, you gave me the idea of searching inside MySQL 8 and I found the solution. Unfortunately, DBFiddle fails to show the result. I had to try on a local MySQL 8 server.